# Spring security clashes with the POST method

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am trying to implement Spring basic auth into the app. I added the folowing lines to application.properties:

```html
  #Security
  security:
    user:
      name: admin
      password: admin
```

So the Spring will create a web security config bean by itself. But I ran some tests and everything works as expected for any method besides POST as it throws 403 status. I browsed the web and discovered that it happens due to csrf protection and I disabled it, creating additional web security config class:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

@Bean
protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
    return http.build();
}
}
```

However, it completely disables the authentication. The user does not need a password and a login to use the resources.
My question is, how do I configure the authentication in a way POST method will not throw 403? Do I need to write a full web security config and delete those 4 lines from application.properties or there is an alternative way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you just added your own custom security configuration which means you are overriding the default one that you can configure using application.properties. So you either configure the default one using application.properties or you create a custom security config. You cant mix and match. I recommend you read the spring security documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/index.html

Comment: i recommend you read the documentation before, and if there is anything unclear there you ask here.